# Is there a way to filter output in Google Chrome's console?

Tags: javascript, console, filtering, flags, google-chrome-devtools

I'm getting a lot of noise from the output of the 3rd party's page i'm currently playing with and i wonder if there's a way to filter the output on the console. Something like Logcat's flags. Is there a way to do that?

EDIT

I found a way to disable the output that was causing the biggest ammount of noise. I clicked with the right-clicked on the console and then disabled the `XMLHttpRequest Logging` option. It's not what i wanted, but it's what i needed.

Comment: Filter in what way? Like by site?

Comment: I'm developing an extension which outputs to the console, and the page also outputs to the console... i'd like to do something like `console.log('extension', 'The message');` and filter the output so i only see stuff flagged with 'extension' instead of the whole output.
EDIT
Or filter by levels: `console.warn()`, `console.error()`

Comment: I see. I don't think that functionality exists in Chrome...

Comment: As for Warn and Error, if you're running the dev channel, I have the filter buttons on the bottom pane: http://i.imgur.com/0VN67.png

Comment: That's not the ideal solution because the noise spans all log levels, but it'll have to do for now. I'm trying to find an extension to help me on that.

Comment: In Firefox, extensions can access virtually every part of the browser. In Chrome, it's a lot more restricted. I don't think a Chrome extension can modify the Developer Tools thing...

Comment: I was thinking about an extension that has the flagging feature. :)

Comment: You can search for a specific text in your error messages, using the search box in the top right corner of the console.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter the Chrome console messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44130085/filter-the-chrome-console-messages)

Answer (score 24):

You can use regular expressions.

For example to exclude the word `browser-sync` I use `^((?!browser-sync).)*$`.

[image]

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31745091/582995)

---

Chrome 44.0.2403.125

Comment: Since the checkbox `Regex` has been removed from the latest chrome, I used `/^((?!browser-sync).)*$/` to indicate that it is a regular expression. Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42044616/6053299).

Comment: On recent version you can just prefix the word to be negated with a `-`, see https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/08/devtools-release-notes#negative-filters

Answer (score 22):

Going further than the above answer comments..

Go in console mode ( Control Shift J on Windows ) , enter this :

```
console.nativeLog = console.log;
```

Then enter this

```
console.log = function( a, b ){ if(a=="extension") console.nativeLog( b ) }
```

The first line keeps the native implementation in a safe spot.
The second line does pretty much what you request.

Works for me.

Answer (score 3):

I just blogged about my solution to this.  I modified Ben Alman's "ba-debug" library and made a modular "Trace" object designed to be used with different modules or areas of the code (defined by you).

Basic usage:

```
   var _trace = new Trace('ModuleName');
```

Then, when you want to trace out any level of diagnostics, you do:

```
   _trace.error('error level message');
   _trace.warn('warning level message');
   _trace.info('information level message');
   _trace.log('log level message');
   _trace.debug('debug level message');
```

Then, in your page, or in your console, you can do this:

```
   Trace.traceLevel('ModuleName', Trace.Levels.warn);
```

Here's my blog [post](http://codemares.blogspot.com/2011/09/much-to-my-chagrin-i-have-been-doing.html) for more detail and the JavaScript file:

Answer (score 2):

If you have control of both the page and extension scripts then you can run both through your own function. In that function you could now control output.

```
var pageErrors = true;
var extErrors = true;

function outputToConsole(message, sender) {
   if (sender == 'page' && pageErrors) { console.write(message); }
   if (sender == 'ext' && extErrors) { console.write(message); }
}
```

Everywhere you want to log replace console.log with outputToConsole()

Comment: I don't have control of the page, unfortunately.

Comment: Hmmm, got me thinking. Check this out on SO. This guy turns logging on and off and even has an example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215392/how-to-quickly-and-conveniently-disable-all-console-log-statements-in-my-code

Comment: Thanks for my first bounty! Any reason you did not flag my post as the answer ?

Answer (score 1):

If regular expressions aren't your thing, there are two other things that you can do:

1. In the Filter input box you can add a string of negative matches that will prevent messages **beginning with those characters** from displaying.

Example:

```
-WARNING -Errorcode -bonk
```

Will suppress messages like the following:

```
WARNING line 234 something else on this line
This message will still display
Errorcode 234: Some error that will be hidden
bonk
```

The only message from the above that would display is:

```
This message will still display
```

2. ANOTHER simple thing you can do is to right-click on any line in the console log and choose the first option from the pop-up context menu: "Hide messages from ___________" (some script name).  This will hide all error messages produced by that script.

To "unhide" those messages again, note that the undesired script was added into the Filter input box - just delete it from there and the messages will return.

Comment: Was actually looking for this solution. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

This is what I just wrote to solve the same problem. Compared to the previous answers, it has the benefit of properly handling multiple arguments to `console.log` and of preventing the absence of window.console.log to throw uncaught exceptions.

```
(function(){
    window.console = window.console||{log:0};
    var nativeLog = window.console.log;
    window.console.log = function() { 
        try {
            // these conditions find all console.log output
            // from bitcoinjs-0.1.3 but not much else
            // (who else ends an extremely short first parameter with a space?)
            if ((arguments.length == 2) 
              && (arguments[0].length <= 5) 
              && (arguments[0].slice(-2) === ': ')
            ) {
                return;
            };
            nativeLog.apply(window.console, arguments);
        } catch(e) {};
    };
})();
```

Comment: I have no idea why someone had downwoted you, based on your answer I was able to create a nice filter for too verbose third party library that spammed the console. Sure, the try-catch block could be a bit more clear what it does, but the rest of it was golden.

Comment: You can probably omit the exception handling (the try and catch lines), but there is a risk of accidentally breaking code. If any of the code you insert, for example the matching itself, ever runs into an exception that the caller of console.log sees, you do something that calling code was not written to expect.

Answer (score 0):

To effectively filter console logs containing **specific phrases**, such as `**"JSON Viewer load**", you can use a regular expression in the filter input. For instance:

```
-/JSON Viewer load/
```

This approach allows you to precisely target logs **with more than one word** in their content. If you want to filter all console logs beginning with `"JSON"`, you could use

```
-JSON
```

However, this broader filter **could potentially omit** some relevant information.

**Be aware:**

Text containing **special characters**, such as parentheses `(` and `)`, must be escaped:

Filtering `"Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener"` would be:

```
-/Uncaught \(in promise\) Error: A listener/
```

> By the way, the error mentioned above will appear in your console due to ad-blocking filters, which are included in Brave and added as extensions in other browsers.

Comment: I hope no one overlooks the preceding minus sign `-` before the initial forward slash `/`.