# How to add negative filter in network tab of Chrome DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to hide some packets in the Network tab of Chrome DevTools. I am having a lot of olark calls that I would like to hide:

> p?j=olark-21408520578584&&c=polleven[...]
> p?j=olark-1408520582743&&c=polleven[...]
> p?j=olark-41408520586905&&c=polleven[...]
> p?j=olark-51408520591078&&c=polleven[...]
> ...

What should I write in the filter to hide these?
`^p?j=olark` does not work, nor does `!p?j=olark`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to filter network requests using Google Chrome developer tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14637278/is-there-a-way-to-filter-network-requests-using-google-chrome-developer-tools)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Note sure you're talking about the Network tab or the Console tab: I'll answer about both cases.

### Network tab

Similar to [Google's search operators](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en), you can use the **minus sign** to filter out stuff in the network view, see the examples below.

Here you have the start network list:

[image]

If you type `-`, you'll see a list of types that you can select to filter:

[image]

Note that at the same time the resource names are filtered to those containing the minus sign:

[image]

For example you can filter out the GET requests:

[image]:

If you instead type a word, it will exclude all resources containing that word:

[image]

### Console tab

At the moment (*) you can't use the minus search operator, but you can use regular expressions.

For example to exclude the word `browser-sync` I use `^((?!browser-sync).)*$`.

[image]

---

(*) Chrome 44.0.2403.125

Comment: With Chrome 60 there is no checkbox 'Regex' anymore so you'd have to add an opening and closing forward slash to your filter expression to trigger RegEx filtering: `/^((?!browser-sync).)*$/`

Comment: @robro on Chrome 60.0.3112.101 (OSX) `/^((?!browser-sync).)*$` is not working for me. It is hiding all logs. Instead I had to use `/^((?!browser-sync).)*$/` (trailing `/` as well)

Comment: @JasonAxelson which is exactly why there is a trailing `/` in my comment ;)

Comment: Haha, I must've missed that character while copy and pasting!

Comment: Ahh to bad they don't support ! (not) I was doing like `!status-code:200` as trying to only see errors in an ocean of request.. but this helps me. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score -3):

It seems as though the feature you are asking about is not supported on chrome.

See:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=133733

Which is tracking a feature request for the functionality that you mention.