# Where has the Google Chrome Console Filter [_] Regex checkbox gone?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

All of the Google Chrome Console documentation pages (and numerous SO answers) show a checkbox labeled "Regex" next to the filter when the filter bar is expanded, e.g., from the [Command Line API Reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference):

[image]

I use it so much that I have macros set up to paste various Regexes into it, so I'm positive I am not crazy and that it existed until very recently. I am using Google Chrome Version 57.0.2987.21 beta (64-bit) on Mac OS X, and it's no longer there:

[image]

Is it gone, have I done something inadvertent to hide it, or what?

---

**Update:** This might be a bug in the Beta channel: [DevTools: [regression] isRegex checkbox is missing on Network and Console filter bars](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=686365&q=regex%20filter%20&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In Chrome 58+ to enter a regex simply enclose the text in `/`, this trick is used in some applications:

```
/\w+::\S/
```

Comment: Did you actually try this in Chrome, or is this a guess? Because it doesn't work. Also, I will update the question, but it may be a bug in the Beta channel: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=686365&q=regex%20filter%20&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Comment: Outstanding. I'll check it out in Canary and hold my breath 'til the fix shows up in Beta.

Answer (score 2):

the approved answer didn't work for me. My version is 80+. I finally figured out that clicking on search opens the interface to search with regex.

I didn't like the search re[image]sults page though.

Comment: Oh: that's the Network tab. Interesting. Although the question was about the Console, thank you for introducing me to the Network Tab's search function, which I'd never explored before. That tiny search results list is not a lot of fun, as you point out.