# Prevent http errors from being logged in browser console

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to figure out how to suppress http request and response errors in my app, for example when a bad request is made to my server, I don't want the error to be logged into the browser console. I've tried overriding the `$exceptionHandler`, but that logic works for all exceptions except HTTP errors, those are still logged to the browser. I've also created HTTP interceptors but the global `400 Bad Request` error appears before the logic that I've put in my `responseError`:

```
'responseError': function (rejection) {
 console.log(rejection);
 return $q.reject();
}
```

That doesn't suppress the error either, any ideas?

EDIT

The error I'm getting is this:
`POST http://localhost:38349/token 400 (Bad Request)`
[image]

Comment: can you copy the output of the log you want to get rid of?

Comment: Not sure why this question was marked as a duplicate, it clearly isn't asking what the responses that are provided in the link are discussing.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Actually Angular doesn't log this.

It's the XMLHttpRequest object that doing that (same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949095/how-can-i-stop-jquery-ajax-from-logging-failures-to-the-console) with JQuery). I extracted the logic from Angular and made [a working standalone example](http://plnkr.co/edit/XMBLaJwIvccjcEi0DXQa):

```
var method = 'POST';
var url404 = '/tnseiartneiasrt/arsntiearsntiasrntiarnstsie';

var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open(method, url404, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr && xhr.readyState == 4) {
    console.log('should have logged an error already :(');
  }
};
xhr.send(null);
```

As you can see, it's the xhr object that logs it. There might be a way to disable all console.log before triggering the xhr request but I think it's better to either

- Redesign your error flow to return a status code of 200 embeded with an internal error code in the body
- Live with the console logging (the average user doesn't even know about the console anyways)

I chose the second option because I think it's easier to understand as it doesn't require extra logic when someone reads your code.

Hope this helps :)