# Catch http error in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I'm not able to catch the http error in the error function call back when posting an http request.

Here is the client side:

```
$http.post('/updateBuildings', 
            $.param(
                {'element_id': element_id}
            )).success(function(data) {
                tmp.GetBuildings(data.new_building_id);         
            }).error(function(data) {
                console.log('response: ',data);
            });

    };
```

The server side is returning an http error deliberately : status code: 401, msg: "Sorry, access 
denied."

[image: http error written by browser to console]

The browser (google chrome) writes to the log by itself (see attachment) but I'm not able to catch the error in angular and present an alert for the user for example.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113286/prevent-http-errors-from-being-logged-in-browser-console

Comment: I dont want to prevent the browser from logging. I want to also handle the error in angular

Comment: Then a try catch block would be the way to go I guess.

Comment: Do you have any interceptors setup? If so, could they be turning failures into successes?

Comment: no, dont have such thing

Answer (score 1):

I've had problems using `success` and `error`: they don't behave quite as I expect with respect to promises chaining and errors. While I'm not sure if that's what's going on here, I would suggest not using `success` and `error`, but use the standard promise `then` / `catch` functions.

```
$http.post('/updateBuildings', $.param({
  'element_id': element_id
})).then(function(response) {
  return tmp.GetBuildings(response.data.new_building_id);         
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log('response: ', error.data);
});
```

Comment: Tried that but still the error is not caught in the angular code