# Ember.js - How to handle error with DS.store.findRecord() method

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, json-api

I am using following simple code to retrieve user
from server.

```
var someUser = this.store.findRecord('user', 0);
```

I am using this for retrieving the user. if user is not found on 0 id,

server returns 404. and error as per json api.

but how do i know about error on client side about it ?

Comment: You can find answer in [docs](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/#toc_code-error-code-substates). Also you are welcome to read [my post](http://blog.gennady.pp.ua/how-to-handle-backend-errors-in-ember-js-properly/) about error handling

Answer (score 4):

Taken from [Ember guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/models/finding-records/):

> Use `store.findRecord()` to retrieve a record by its type and ID. This
>   will return a **promise** that fulfills with the requested record.

Since the return value is a promise, you can use it as any other promise:

```
this.store.findRecord('user', 0)
  .then(function(user){
    // user has been found
    someUser = user;
  }).catch(function(error){
    // user not found or any other error
  });
```

Comment: Answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949095/how-can-i-stop-jquery-ajax-from-logging-failures-to-the-console

Comment: Error in console persit but te server response 404 code