# catch block inside the model() hook in emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Am I allowed to add a `catch` method in my `model` hook? i.e. something like this:

```
model(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('shop', params.slug)
    .catch( () => 
        this.transitionTo('welcome.shops.index'))
    }
}
```

My goal is to route the user whenever he entered the incorrect `slug`. If there is a better approach to my desire behaviour please suggest it. Would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36233353/ember-js-how-to-handle-error-with-ds-store-findrecord-method

Comment: Yes, you are. I couldn't think of a better way

Comment: An alternative would be to use the error event: https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/#toc_the-code-error-code-event

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to do so, but I would not consider it best practice. Let's dig a little bit deeper in what you are doing:

`this.store.findRecord('shop', params.slug)` returns a Promise. `Promise.catch()` returns a Promise (and registers a function to be executed if the promise rejects).

So your model hook returns the Promise from `findRecord` but also registers a function to be executed if this Promise rejects.

You should use Route's [`error` event](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.0/classes/Route/events/error?anchor=error) to execute logic if your model Promise rejects.