# Error bubbles to console even though it is handled

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, fetch, isomorphic-fetch-api

I am using `isomorphic-fetch` to perform AJAX requests from my `react-redux` application. In my api middleware I have the following function which calls the external resource:

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

function callApi({ endpoint, method, body, params = {} }) {
    let route = generateRoute(endpoint, params);
    return fetch(route, generateFetchOptions(method, body))
        .then(response =>  {
            if (!response.ok) {
                return Promise.reject(response);
            }

            return response.json();
        });
}
```

The above function is called by the following piece of code:

```
return callApi(callAPI).then(
    response => next(actionWith({
        response,
        type: successType,
        statusCode: 200
    })),
    error => error.json().then(errorObject => {
        return next(actionWith({
            type: failureType,
            statusCode: errorObject.statusCode,
            error: errorObject.message || 'Something bad happened'
        }));
    })
);
```

If I reject with `Promise.reject(response)` the error is being handled by the error handler, but for some reason the error also bubbles to the browser console (in my case Chrome).

Here is a screenshot from the console which shows what is happening (`api.js:34` is the second line of the `callApi` method):

[image: console log]

Comment: Which error specifically? The `response` you're rejecting with isn't even an `Error`.

Comment: Any error which I return as Promise.reject. I do handle them but they somehow manage to get to the console

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your console. The response object is not an error and shouldn't be shown as such on the console. However, there are many other things in your code that could go wrong and cause an error that would be shown there.

Comment: So `error.json' is a promise-returning function!?

Comment: `error` is an object with a function called `json` which returns a promise. It is part of the `fetch` API.

Comment: @Bergi I added a screenshot of the console. Hope this somehow helps.

Comment: The browser shows broken http calls... Is that the issue?

Comment: That's not an error from any javascript, that's just the browser telling you by default that there was a http error (not found resource).

Answer (score 2):

This is the usual behavior (in probably every browser?) when hitting an error during an HTTP request (no matter whether a linked image cannot be found, or an XHR fails). No matter *if* and *how* you handle those errors, they will **always** be logged to the console. There is no way to suppress this behavior.

References:

- [Provide a way not to display 404 XHR errors in console](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=124534)
- [How can I stop jQuery.ajax() from logging failures to the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949095/how-can-i-stop-jquery-ajax-from-logging-failures-to-the-console)