# Is there a way I can stop a failed HTTP request from showing in the browser console as an error?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
 entityResource.save(formData,
    function (result) {
        ....
    }, function (result) {
        ...
    });
```

If the function save fails and returns http://abc.com/api/Content 400 (Bad Request) then this is 
valid as I display a message.

Is there a way I can stop this showing as a failure in the console of Chrome?

Comment: console is browser component, you cannot control this using your javascript, unless you write a chrome plugin or some thing like that.

Comment: Is there nothing I can do that can wrap this in a try / catch or something like that ?

Comment: You can try re-writing the `console.log`, `console.error` functions. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1215400/1012381 for an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can response the http code :200, then reponse content like json:  {error_code: 400, error_msg: "business error"}