# remove asserts from javascript code for production version

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to remove asserts (`console.assert`) from JavaScript code for production version? Maybe there is some software that can be configured to sort of build JavaScript and remove asserts?

**UPDATE *_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**

I've installed GRUNT and groundskeeper plugin. This is what my Gruntfile.js has:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({
    groundskeeper: {
        compile: {
            files: {
              'calculator/add.js': 'calculator/add.js'
            },
            options: {
                console: false
            }
        }
    }
});

// These plugins provide necessary tasks.
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-groundskeeper');
```

The problem is with when I run `grunt groundskeeper` I get the following error:

```
Running "groundskeeper:compile" (groundskeeper) task
Warning: Line 2: Invalid left-hand side in assignment Use --force to continue.
```

I assume that the problem is with this line:

```
'calculator/add.js': 'calculator/add.js'
```

Since if I replace it with the following:

```
'path/to/result.js': 'path/to/source.js'
```

Everything works fine:

```
Running "groundskeeper:compile" (groundskeeper) task
>> File path/to/result.js created empty, because its counterpart was empty.
>> 1 files read, 0 cleaned.
```

What's wrong with the my original line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to quickly and conveniently disable all console.log statements in my code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215392/how-to-quickly-and-conveniently-disable-all-console-log-statements-in-my-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using the grunt-groundkeeper plugin for this:
https://github.com/Couto/grunt-groundskeeper

If you're not using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started) yet, I really recommend using it for JavaScript projects. Explaining how to use Grunt itself is out of scope of this question.

The following example config sets removing all logging statements in the `www/scripts.min.js` file as the default task.

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        groundskeeper: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'www/scripts.min.js': 'www/scripts.min.js'
                }
            }
        });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-groundskeeper');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['groundskeeper']);
};
```

Comment: That's a really useful plugin. Ditto, Grunt is amazing!

Comment: Thanks, can you please elaborate on how you use it exactly for that purpose?

Comment: Got you! I'll try it and get back if I've got any questions :).

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it might be a bad idea to write the output to the same file as the input.

Comment: The same problem persists event if I change destination

Comment: Thank you, I've already figured out the problem. It happened that `www/scripts.min.js` contained invalide javascript. Didn't know that groundskeeper actually runs the scripts.

Answer (score 3):

make assert as an empty function in your production

```
console.assert = function(){}
```

if you can check it is a production version then put the code like,

```
if (production) {
   console.assert = function(){}
}
```

for old IE shim

```
  if (typeof console == "undefined" || typeof console.assert == "undefined"){
       var console = { assert : function() {} }; 
    }
```

Comment: Thank, but this may not be an option for IE, since `console` object doesn't exist until console is opened.

Comment: that you can check with some shim with out that it will work in IE10,9,8 only IE7 need that

Comment: Thank you! Yet Remco Haszing options seems to be a best solution. I upvoted your answer anyway :).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215392/how-to-quickly-and-conveniently-disable-all-console-log-statements-in-my-code its similar question