# How do I supress a warning after ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Can't seem to figure this one out.

I have a warning I want to supress. No problem with: `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE)` 
But when I make an ajax request that loads some data, and that data generates that warning I want to supress, it shows up in my injected code.

So my question, is there a way to supress those warnings?

Comment: error_reporting( 0 );

Comment: I hope this post can help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215392/how-to-quickly-and-conveniently-disable-all-console-log-statements-in-my-code

Comment: You should rather try and fix the code that generates the warning in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

use exceptions

```
<?php

try{
   // YOUR LOGIC GOES HERE
} catch(Exception $ex) {
  // YOUR LOGIC GOES HERE
}

?>
```