# Console log set log level

Tags: jquery, logging

I am having web application which uses jquery and backbone in front end.
I am receiving/sending big amount of data and i store some of the values which needed for internal process.
The data which send and receive should logged into console if and only if cookie set to log level (trace,info,debug etc..) for the developer need.
Please let me know any libraries or utilities available.

Comment: use console.log('Text here')

Comment: @AsadNauman I am using that. The question is not that. question is how to reduce log level like console.info,console.trace etc.

Comment: you are already setting flag in cookie.. check this flag before logging

Comment: @AsadNauman I have 1000 console log statements. do i need to check it for every page? . Can i get functionalities like log4f slog4j where if you set log level only those logs get printed.

Comment: found this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215392/how-to-quickly-and-conveniently-disable-all-console-log-statements-in-my-code

Comment: You can't just write a custom log method that adds a log-level parameter?

Comment: @AsadNauman thanks let me check.

Comment: @pingul i am searching for the same.:)

Comment: @Madhukar Hebbar is your issue resolved?