# Can you silence errors and warnings from external js scripts?

Tags: javascript, console, warnings, external

I have no choice but to use some ancient js lib provided by a client. So no way I can fix the errors, and no way I can find a better solution. The source is unalterable.

Given that scenario, is there any way I can suppress the warnings or errors from that external library? Even if it is something like they had a console log somewhere in there. I'd like to prevent this script from flooding my console with unnecessary information.

Anyone dealt with that before?

Comment: Have you checked this question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634926/how-to-disable-console-log-messages-based-on-criteria-from-specific-javascript-s

Comment: @jmargolistv - Just read it over, it looks like selective console suppression and not really a mute for an entire script. My biggest pain is the exceptions and invalid state errors. It's a 2 page wall of useless on every click.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative of the answer of jeanfrg is to "filter" in relation of the string. So that you can still keep the wished one.

Like this:

```
export const setupWarning = () => {
  const originalWarn = console.warn

  console.warn = (...args) => {
    // Silent specific warning
    if(args[0].toString().includes('a substring of the warning I want to ignore'){ 
      return 
    }

    // Call the original console.warn with the provided arguments
    originalWarn.apply(console, [...args])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:**

- This is dirty!
- This is not recommended!

... but this is how you can do it

```js
var newConsole = jQuery.extend(true, {}, console);
console.log = console.info = console.error = function noop(){}; //etc

// some old crusty lib that you cannot modify

console.log("hey!");
newConsole.log("hey!");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not bad and dirty is OK if it's just to get rid of nuisance pollution, but this is only good for silencing console. I'm really being plagued by DOMExceptions, InvalidStateError, etc. I want all noise from the external sources to go away. Thanks though

Comment: @KaiQing unfortunately I don't know of a way to silence those.

Comment: No problem. I've been doing this for over 10 years and I never thought to try until now. Live and learn