# Unwanted Output In Console

Tags: google-apps-script, logging, developer-tools

I've started to get some strange output in my developer console.  I was wondering if there was a way to turn it off.

> Net state changed from IDLE to BUSY

That outputs whenever anything server side is called, you can imagine that it might cause a lot of clutter.

Comment: yes this definitely has only just started in the last few days or so.  No changes on my scripts yet console shows the message over and over.  It is coming from a warden source as the answer below surmises.  And I am using lots of  google.script.run as the 2nd answer suggests.  But still, the message wasn't there before so can't imagine it's an infinite loop causing it else would have always been there.  Not a problem I guess - just odd....

Comment: @SoftTimur : "Does anyone know how to get rid of these messages? Using Filter is not a perfect solution, because I have other keyword to filter with."  What do you mean by this? Are you looking to block Google Apps Script from writing to the web browser console ? What web browser are you using? Possible related [How to disable console.log messages based on criteria from specific javascript source (method, file) or message contents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39634926/1595451)

Answer (score 2):

I was faced out with this issue also, tried to google, but no results.

Do not worry. This output appears when you call add-on back-end by calling `google.script.run`. It is default output for debugging the state of a connection.
Probably you have a loop that gets information from the add-on backend infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the messages are coming from warden source.

To solve this, you can simply right click (Windows) or double click (Mac) to bring up the help menu. Then access Filter and click the source of the element you want to filter out of your console. It should then disappear.

Let me know how that works

Comment: I had already filtered them out but would much prefer no messages at all.  I'm not sure why they just started to show this morning.