# Google Apps Script, print and don't render my css file?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications, console.log

I've un other problem, with my google apps scpript, now html, css, and js files are ok. But when I call a function

```
.gs
function func(){
  var message="";
  try {
   
    );
  }
  catch (error) {
     message="Errors "+ 
      "\r\nMessage: " + error.message
      + "\r\nFile: " + error.fileName
      + "\r\nLine: " + error.lineNumber;
  }
  finally {
    if(message=="") {
      message="Completed Successfully";
    }
    Logger.log(message);
  }
}
```

with

```
.js
function onFailure(error){
    console.log("onFailure: " + error);
}

function onSuccess(resp) {
    console.log("onSuccess: "+ resp);
}
google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure).withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).func();
```

the console show this logs, and not my

```
Net state changed from IDLE to BUSY
Net state changed from BUSY to IDLE
null
```

I just try to follow much video but I can't see the error.
I don't understand where I'm wrong, please help me :’(.

Comment: Where is hotelworksync()? and what is func?

Comment: @Cooper my bad it was a typo

Comment: Where is your html and where are your script tags?

Comment: @Cooper I don't understand how you might need the html, how could the error be related to html?

Comment: google.script.run is meant to be use to send data from clientside javascript to server side gs functions.

Comment: @Cooper I don't think that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZRyxJZRlrWM&ab_channel=Get__itDone%21

Comment: I thought that in your function `func` returns no value. So, in your situation, when `return message;` is put to the bottom of the function `func`, is that the result you expect?

Comment: @Tanaike if I call from backend this funck func prints the message to the console

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. I had commented about the returned value from Google Apps Script to Javascript.

Comment: @Tanaike ok I see the error now thanks for your help, I don't know why I don't think

Comment: @Tanaike Sorry but you know why the console messages start with:

Net state changed from IDLE to BUSY
Net state changed from BUSY to IDLE

My question is, how I can Fix these boring problems?

Answer (score 0):

Posting this for documentation purposes.

As [mentioned by Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70724456/google-apps-script-print-and-dont-render-my-css-file#comment125032711_70724456) in comments, you need to add `return message` to your function if you want to actually return the value (ref: [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)).

Regarding `Net state changed from IDLE to BUSY`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51142087/10612011).