# Disabling console access for specific Javascript files

Tags: javascript

In my current project with lots of dependencies I need a way to disable console access for specific libraries so that those files can't use any of the console functionality.

I could of course disable console functionality by simply finding and replacing it in the library bundle, but as this project has a lot of dependencies that would make updating libraries a huge hassle.

I'm aware that I can disable console functionality by overwriting it with an empty function block:

```
console.log = function(){};
```

But that disables the console functionality for the entire project. So im looking for an implementation, or a line of code with which I can disable console functionality for a specific file or code block.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is it that you are trying to block?

Comment: I'm trying to block specific libraries from using any of the console functions(log, error, warning) so that they can't log anything to the browser console.

Comment: In what way are you _mixing_ different JS file contents into one context?

Comment: I assume this is only for production that you want to remove them? Are you using webpack? If so the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41040266/remove-console-logs-with-webpack-uglify) might help

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do it for already compiled JS. However similar effect (console logs removal) is definitely possible at building phase with bundling tools such as webpack.

Comment: I am using webpack for bundling, but as I need console logs in the production version too (for bug reporting) I can't do away with them for the entire project.

Comment: Another solution maybe https://github.com/webpack-contrib/imports-loader and you "mock" console object just for your dependencies (node_modules ?)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable console.log messages based on criteria from specific javascript source (method, file) or message contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634926/how-to-disable-console-log-messages-based-on-criteria-from-specific-javascript-s)

Comment: _I can't do away with them for the entire project._ Check `include/exclude` options of [`UglifyjsWebpackPlugin`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Write a *white-listing* "middleware" for `console.log`

```js
// Preserve the old console.log
const log = console.log;

// Used a dictionary because it's faster than lists for lookups
const whiteListedFunctions = {"hello": true};

// Whitelisting "middleware". We used the function's name "funcName"
// as a criteria, but it's adaptable
const isWhitelisted = callerData => callerData.funcName in whiteListedFunctions;

// Replacing the default "console.log"
console.log = arg => {
  const stack = new Error().stack.split("at")[2].trim().split(' ');
  const fileParts = stack[1].substr(1, stack[1].length - 2).split(':');

  const callerData = {
    funcName: stack[0],
    file: fileParts.slice(0, fileParts.length - 2).join(':'),
    lineColNumber: fileParts.slice(fileParts.length - 2).join(':')
  };
  
  if (isWhitelisted(callerData)) {      // Filtering happens here
    log(arg);
  }
};

// Define the calling functions
function hello() { console.log("hello"); }
function world() { console.log("world"); }

hello(); // => Prints hello
world(); // => Doesn't print anything
```

## Method explanation

- You can do this by creating a *whitelist* *(or blacklist)* that will contain your *filtering criteria*. For example it may contain the **name of the functions that call `console.log`** or maybe the **file name**, or even the **line and column numbers**.
- After that you create your **whitelisting "middleware"**. This will take the *caller function data* and decide if it can log stuff or not. This will be done based on the previously defined *whitelist*. You can choose your preferred criteria in this "middleware".
- Then you actually replace `console.log` by overriding with your *new logger*. This logger will take as an argument the message to log (maybe multiple arguments?). In this function you also need to find the data relating to the **caller function** (which wanted to call `console.log`).
- Once you have the *caller data*, you can then use your *whitelisting middleware* to decide if it can log stuff

## Getting information about the caller function

This part is a little "hacky" (but it got the job done in this case). We basically create an **`Error`** and check its `stack` attribute like this `new Error().stack`. Which will give us this trace

> Error
>       at console.log.arg [as log] (https://stacksnippets.net/js:25:7)
>       at hello (https://stacksnippets.net/js:41:11)
>       at https://stacksnippets.net/js:48:1

After processing (split, map, etc...) the trace we get the caller function data. For example here we have

- The caller function's name: *hello*
- The file name: *https://stacksnippets.net/js*
- The line and column number: *41:11* (watch out for minifiers)

***This bit was inspired by [VLAZ's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz) answer in [How to disable console.log messages based on criteria from specific javascript source (method, file) or message contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634926/how-to-disable-console-log-messages-based-on-criteria-from-specific-javascript-s/39648992#39648992), so make sure to check it out. Really good and thorough post.***

## Note

To make sense of the trace we can do `new Error().stack.split("at")[INDEX].trim().split(' ')` where `INDEX` is the position of the *function call* you want to target in the *stack trace*. So if you want to get a different *"level"* that the one used in this example, try changing `INDEX`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can disable console logs from files based on their path! Here's a solution:

```
// in ./loud-lib.js
module.exports = {
    logsSomething: () => console.log('hello from loud-lib')
}
```

```
// in ./silent-lib.js
module.exports = {
    logsSomething: () => console.log('hello from silent-lib')
}
```

```
// in ./index.js
const loud = require('./loud-lib');
const silent = require('./silent-lib');

// save console.log
const log = console.log;
// redefinition of console.log
console.log = (...params) => {
    // define regexp for path of libraries that log too much
    const loudLibs = [/loud-lib/];
    // check if the paths logged in the stacktract match with at least one regexp
    const tooLoud = !!loudLibs.find(reg => reg.test(new Error().stack));
    // log only if the log is coming from a library that doesn't logs too much
    if (!tooLoud) log(...params);
};

loud.logsSomething();
silent.logsSomething();
```

```
$ node ./index.js
hello from silent-lib
```

This is based on the fact that `new Error()` produces a stack trace that identifies from which file is the error coming from (recursively).

Based on this observation, you can define an array of regular expression that match the name of libraries you don't want to hear logs from. You can get really specific and creative with the re-definition of `console.log`, but I kept it simple.

**However, be aware of this (especially when using Webpack)**: if you bundle all your JS assets into one single `bundle.js`, the stacktrace will always point to `bundle.js`, thus logging everything. You'll have to go further from my code, for example by using [stack-source-map](https://github.com/chemzqm/stack-source-map), but I don't have sufficient details on your project to deliver a solution. I hope the ideas above are sufficient for you.

Answer (score -1):

Just redefine the console to log over a condition, your condition of course will be a check over which library is accessing the function:

```js
// Your condition, could be anything
let condition = true;
/* Redefine the console object changing only the log function with your new version and keeping all the other functionalities intact
*/
let console = (old => ({
    ...old,
    log: text => { if (condition) old.log(text) }
}))(window.console)

// Redefine the old console
window.console = console;

console.log('hello!')
```

Hope it helped :)

Comment: And how does one check which library is accessing the function?