# How do I tap into all console.error messages

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get all of the `console.error` messages caught by dedicated error handler (which is supposed to trigger certain actions upon some specific error) and I'm trying to leverage `window.onerror` callback for that purpose.

So far, I can't succeed even with my basic set-up, like

#### listener.js

```
(function () {
  window.onerror = function (msg) {
    console.log("I got the error:", msg);
  };
})();
```

and

#### thrower.js

```
(function () {
  console.error("sample error");
})();
```

both are loaded as a static assets from within `<head>` section of the very basic

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="assets/listen.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/throw.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    here I go
  </body>
</html>
```

and served by trivial express app:

#### index.js

```
import express from "express";
import { join } from "path";

const app = express();

app.use("/assets", express.static(join(__dirname, "public")));

app.use("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(join(__dirname, "index.html"));
});

app.listen(9000, () => console.log("listen :9000"));
```

What I expect is getting sample error message echoed with custom prefix (`'I got the error: '`) but there's no extra output in the console, so I assume, the sample error wasn't ever caught.

So, the question is: what exactly am I missing here?

Comment: `console.error()` doesn't throw an error in the traditional sense, it's just printing a string to the console with "error" formatting.

Comment: Calling `console.error` should never "*trigger certain actions*" other than logging an error to the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`console.error` is just console.log with `Error:` in red. It is not a [window.error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw) so the thrower needs to do

```
(function () {
  throw "sample error";
})();
```

You are able (***but it is not recommended***) to override the native console.error

Here I added a throw to the log

```js
const err = console.error; // save the console.error method
console.error = str => { err(str); throw `'Throwing error':'${str}'`;  };

console.error("My Error")
```

Comment: looks like what I've been looking for was *'override `console.error`'* and you seem to address that with your snippet, thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
(function () {
  console.error("sample error");
})();
```

This is not throwing any error it's just logging some piece of text to console.

If you want to throw an error - u should use [throw statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw)

```
(function () {
  throw new Error('my error');
})();
```

Comment: Because I was only going to comment, then changed my mind and now am looking to see if we can override the console.error

Comment: Why we can't override console error? `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(console, 'error')`: `{writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true, value: ƒ}`

Comment: I [just did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65627293/295783)

Comment: @mplungjan yeh, but I am not sure this code should be public :D

Comment: Yep, excuse me for misunderstanding

Comment: @Drag13 [you can hack the console a lot if you wish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39648992/). However, I wouldn't recommend changing the behaviour of the logging unless you just want to disable, say, `console.info` or `console.debug` messages or something.

Comment: @VLAZ Totally agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

As @Drag13 and @mplungjan `console.log()` does not throw errors so you can't catch them using `window.onerror`.

You have 2 choices to accomplish your goal, either change all of your `console.error(error)` to `throw error`

or override the `console.error` property to handle thus error logs, like this:

```
console.error = function (msg) {
    console.log("I got the error:", msg);
};
```

Comment: While it is technically valid, please don't use the second method, overwriting built in functions is like laying a minefield for future devs.