# Removing log statements in Create React App without ejecting

Tags: create-react-app, uglifyjs

I use lots of `console.log()` statements while developing Apps (and I mean **LOTS**). How exactly can I remove them without `"ejecting"` from a
**Create React App** 
What I considered but not sure how exactly to implement:

In my package.json:

```
 "build": "react-scripts build && uglifyjs --compress drop_console build/static/js/main.xxxxx.js  -o build/static/js/main.xxxxx.js
```

However How exactly can I know the `hash` suffix on the `main.js` file so I can call this command and save the output js file with same filename

Comment: are you trying to remove the lines of code or just the log output? would fixing the latter suffice?

Comment: Suppress the log output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to suppress log output you could wrap `console.log` and use that instead

```
const log = (...msgs) => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') console.log(...msgs)
}
```

You can import / export this, but that sounds like a pain. Seems like a good thing to add to `global`

```
global.log = log

global.log('will only log in dev')
```

Comment: can you elaborate on using the global command to supress the console logs.

Comment: oh nothing special about `global` in this case.. could use `window` as well. I just mean you can write your own `log` function that only outputs in dev mode (which create-react-app uses when running `npm start`) and put that log function on something accessible without having to import it everywhere (like global / window)

Comment: With this approach you'll have to make sure all devs on your team use this specific log function. And they won't because some of them will always forget to use it.

Comment: couldn't a malicious user flip the runtime value of the variable and then see the logs?

Comment: @AlexChannelmeter this is client side. a malicious user already has access to everything that's on the client

Comment: @azium that is true, I agree

Answer (score 13):

Add this to index.js

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') {
  console.log = () => {}
}
```

Note that this will only suppress the messages, it will not strip them from your deployed code.

### Note Nov 2020

Don't do this for library modules, it will disable console.log for the parent project.

### Update Sept 2020

There is some movement on this issue on the CRA repo... go give it support/thumbs up here https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/9222

References:
[How to quickly and conveniently disable all console.log statements in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215392/how-to-quickly-and-conveniently-disable-all-console-log-statements-in-my-code)

Comment: As a beginner, I think this answer fits me better. :)

Comment: I'd also override the other console methods like console.debug, console.warn, console.info depending on what your team uses.

Comment: couldn't a malicious user flip the runtime value of the variable and then see the logs?

Comment: If there are any security implications of leaving log messages for your web app then clearly you should strip logs in the build process. I personally use https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra to do this with `addBabelPlugin('transform-remove-console')` in my config-overrides.js file.

Answer (score 4):

Do this in package.json scripts:

```
 "build": "./scripts/build.sh"
```

and then in your project:

`scripts/build.sh` looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e;
cd "$(dirname $(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE"))"  # cd to project root

react-scripts build 

for f in build/static/js/*.js; do

  uglifyjs --compress drop_console "$PWD/$f" -o "$PWD/$f"

done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this combo of packages to override the config:

**Note**: from the document of [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired/#rewire-your-app-), this would break the the "guarantees" that CRA provides. So you should be careful before using it.

```
npm i -D customize-cra react-app-rewired babel-plugin-transform-remove-console
```

Modify your package.json, replace `react-scripts` to `react-app-rewired` except the `reject`. Once complete, your scripts should look like this:

```
"scripts": {
 "start": "react-app-rewired start",
 "build": "react-app-rewired build",
 "test": "react-app-rewired test",
 "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

Then create a file under the root directory:

```
touch config-overrides.js
```

```
// config-overrides.js
const { override, addBabelPlugins } = require('customize-cra')

module.exports = override(
  addBabelPlugins(
    "transform-remove-console"
  )
)
```

Finally, after running `npm run build`, all `console.log` gone.

Answer (score 0):

I use this setup. I still need console log while in dev.

```
// config-overrides.js
const { override, addBabelPlugins } = require('customize-cra')

module.exports = override(
  process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development' && addBabelPlugins(
    "transform-remove-console"
  )
)
```