# Regarding $location.$$absUrl multiple condition

Tags: angularjs

Can we check condition like below if not then what is other way??? I need to show console.log only below URl.

`$location.$$absUrl.includes('localhost' || 'qa1' || 'cat1')`

Below are my URL:

https://localhost:9005/

https://qa1.abc.com/

https://cat1.abc.com/

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?  you can current url from `var absUrl = $location.absUrl();`

Comment: @ Shashank Vivek need to show console.log on mention URL.... else hide console.log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to achieve what you expect, you should use regex pattern.

```
// If my domain contain localhost OR qua1 or cat1.
if (!$location.absUrl().match(/(localhost|qa1|cat1)/)) {
    // then override console.log to empty function.
    console.log = function(){ }; 

    //Is equal to do : window['console']['log'] = function(){ };
}
```

**UPDATE**

if you want to  [disable all kind of console output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215392/how-to-quickly-and-conveniently-disable-all-console-log-statements-in-my-code) check this other topic

Comment: Thanks for sharing... -:)-:)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var absUrl = $location.absUrl();
if(absUrl.match(/(localhost|qa1|cat1)/)){
   console.log(absUrl)
}
```