# Disable all console message In Express js

Tags: node.js, express

I have used many console.log() in my Express js app. How can I disable all these console.log message by using npm script?
For example:"nodemon index.js DEBUG=false"

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215392/how-to-quickly-and-conveniently-disable-all-console-log-statements-in-my-code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to quickly and conveniently disable all console.log statements in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215392/how-to-quickly-and-conveniently-disable-all-console-log-statements-in-my-code)

Answer (score 1):

Using `console.log()` print log messages to the terminal is common practice in development. **But these functions are synchronous** when the destination is a terminal or a file, so they are **not suitable for production**.

Instead of using `console.log()` use a special debugging module like [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug).

However, the simple and easy approach is to put this code at the callback function of your `app.listen()`:

```
// server.js

app.listen(3000, () => {

  if(!process.env.DEBUG){
     console.log = function(){}
  }

 // when DEBUG = false all console.log will not log
  console.log('server started')
});
```

---

For more [Express.js best practices: performance and reliability](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html) checkout their official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this plugin which removes all console.* calls.

```
npm install babel-plugin-transform-remove-console --save
```

add a .babelrc file with theses configurations

```
{
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "plugins": ["transform-remove-console"]
    }
  }
}
```