# It is possible catch global error on react

Tags: reactjs

I tried to implement error boundary by https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html, but it catches only rendering errors.

It is possible to implement something like global try/catch on `react` and catch errors also on async processes and handlers?

Something like:

```
try {
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
} catch (error) {
    console.log("CAUGHT AN ERROR!!!!!!!")
    console.log(error);
    ReactDOM.render(<ErrorComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));

}
```

Comment: Error Boundaries catch, not only issues in render, but also lifecycle-related errors. In other words, it catches most error your component could throw, except async operations and event handlers

Comment: You can override `console.error` and try handling in it.

Comment: @Rajesh maybe can share the link to example? I tried https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/104/how-to-override-the-console-methods-in-javascript but it looks like does not work for me

Comment: @EdgarasKarka Long back I made this as a [test fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/2pwrth00/). You can take it as a reference. Idea is to capture all exceptions, no matter the origin. [Stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215392/how-to-quickly-and-conveniently-disable-all-console-log-statements-in-my-code) may also help

Answer (score 7):

React 16 has a new feature called error boundaries. You can search more about this. Your problem is solved by error boundary like this :
Ex :

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    // Update state so the next render will show the fallback UI.
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    // You can also log the error to an error reporting service
    logErrorToMyService(error, info);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      // You can render any custom fallback UI
      return <h1>Something went wrong.</h1>;
    }

    return this.props.children; 
  }
}
```

And you can wrap your App component like this. It will catch all error :

```
<ErrorBoundary>
  <App />
</ErrorBoundary>
```

You can read more about here. https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html

Comment: Are you talking about if API failure cases? If I am not wrong ??

Comment: yes, or other example: `<div onClick={()=>throw 'Error'} />`

Comment: Worth quoting from [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html): "Error boundaries do **not** catch errors for: Event handlers (learn more) [and] Asynchronous code (e.g. setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame callbacks)".

Answer (score 2):

One way is to override global `console.error` method.

```
 var console=(function(oldCons){
     return {
         log: function(text){
             oldCons.log(text);
         },
         info: function (text) {
             oldCons.info(text);
         },
         warn: function (text) {
             oldCons.warn(text);
         },
         error: function (text) {
             oldCons.error(text);
             ReactDOM.render(<div>ERROR</div>, document.getElementById('root'))
         }
     };
 }(window.console));

 // catch unhandled promises
 window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", (event) => {
   console.error(event.reason);
 });
```