# How to Disable Text to speech Using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, speech-synthesis

I have created a Samsung smart-tv app using javascript and now I want to disable the TTS in this app but don't know how I can do this please help.

I have tried using `window.speechSynthesis` but it is not working don't know why.
currently what i have done is when window load i call an init() function

```
function init(){
    if ('speechSynthesis' in window) {
              var synthesis = window.speechSynthesis;
              synthesis.cancel();

            } else {
              console.log('Text-to-speech not supported.');
            }

}
```

but it does not work and  so **finally i want to disable the feature of Text to speech from my applicatio**n

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `window.speechSynthesis` member? I've seen `console.log` disabled in the same manner. I.e - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215392/how-to-quickly-and-conveniently-disable-all-console-log-statements-in-my-code

Comment: you want your users to not be able to use TTS? why? synthesis.cancel() doesn't disable TTS, just stops any ongoing speech

Comment: @tudor.gergely yes i dont want TTS on my app so  can you please tell me what can disable TTS ?

Comment: @enhzflep I did not get

Comment: @Nitintiwari in that case you can check my answer

Comment: @Nitintiwari - pardon? Can you re-phrase that in a complete sentence? It makes no sense to me whatsoever.

Comment: Why would you want make your app less accessible to people with visual impairments?

Comment: 'delete window.speechSynthesis' call it in top of js this will delete speech Synthesis  from window.

Comment: @SlimCoder is this even a method ?? I tried but nothing happened

Answer (score 2):

Please have a good reason to do so, disabling voice over is never a good choice. You are basically removing access to people with visual impairments and even if you did a bad job at making your app accessible that will always be better than just disabling it.

Having said that, there's no way to disable voice over using javascript but you can disable it by adding the following tag inside `<widget>` in your `config.xml` file:

```
<tizen:metadata key="http://samsung.com/tv/metadata/use.voiceguide" value="false" />
```

Comment: Thank you for this reply, it really helped me out when developing an app that the Samsung TTS service doesn't support the UI language of the app

Comment: here's the docs if anyone is looking https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/guides/fundamentals/configuring-tv-applications.html

Comment: Reached this post recently, but it seems adding the tag in config.xml doesn't work as expected - when the application is loaded onto device, the Voice Guide is still working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can't disable that feature. The SpeechSynthesis api is if you want to add extra functionality, not for disabling the native feature (which can only be disabled by users of your app from the TV/browser settings).

As written here: https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/legacy-platform-library/tv-functionality/accessibility.html

`If user turns on Accessibility option for TTS in menu, TTS will read contents of HTML elements automatically.`

You can try 2 things (which might not work):

1. Run every 1s (or more often) speechSynthesis.cancel() in a setInterval (I'm not sure this will stop the native TTS of the TV though).

`setInterval(() => window.speechSynthesis.cancel(), 1000)`

2. Replace window.speechSynthesis.speak with an empty function at the beginning of your app (considering Samsung TV uses this for speaking).

`window.speechSynthesis.speak = () => {}`

Comment: i tried both things but none of these work so  i have a question does it speak only about focused element?

Comment: most likely yes, it reads the focused elements if TTS is enabled

Comment: @Nitintiwari how did you try the above methods? what did you expect to happen and what happened?

Comment: i called this methods in onload method

Comment: var init = function () {window.setInterval(speak, 1000) } then init wil be called as <body onload="init()"> and speak will look like this function speak(){
 var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('');
 window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
}