# How to disable or remove Socket.Io log message in user browser?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I made an app that use socket.io.
It's time to put in production.
Before that, i want to remove or disable all socket.io error log in Client Side( the browser of user, So by inspecting console, he will not see the error).

Error is available at this link below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMDib.jpg

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to quickly and conveniently disable all console.log statements in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215392/how-to-quickly-and-conveniently-disable-all-console-log-statements-in-my-code)

Comment: Thanks. The link you provided give me an idea.  `window['console']['error'] = function(){};`   But I notice that it's erased. Socket.io still logging error.

Comment: as long as its set before socket.io runs then it wont output https://playcode.io/774681/

Answer (score 0):

```
console['error'] = function(){}
```

did the job before all others scripts.
Thanks