# TypeScript expression is not callable when trying to disable console methods

Tags: typescript, logging, console

I want to quickly disable all console.[log, time, error] messages in my code.
I am aware of [what has been asked before for javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215392/how-to-quickly-and-conveniently-disable-all-console-log-statements-in-my-code).  But Typescript is complaining of my "solution" bellow:

```js
    const konsole = {
        log:()=>{},
        time:()=>{},
        timeEnd:()=>{},
        error:()=>{}
    }
    (!dev) && console = konsole
```

Where `dev` is a boolean that is true when I am in development mode.

Typescript complaints: `This expression is not callable.` I don't understand the complaint and what should I do instead.

Comment: have you tried with `Object.assign(global, { console: konsole })` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code as it stands:

```
    const konsole = {
        log:()=>{},
        time:()=>{},
        timeEnd:()=>{},
        error:()=>{}
    }
    (!dev) && console = konsole
```

Is interpreted as this:

```
    const konsole = ({
        log:()=>{},
        time:()=>{},
        timeEnd:()=>{},
        error:()=>{}
    }(!dev) && console = konsole);
```

You are trying to call an object as a function, which is why TypeScript is warning you against this runtime error.

You can either use semicolons or remove the parentheses around `!dev`:

```
    const konsole = {
        log:()=>{},
        time:()=>{},
        timeEnd:()=>{},
        error:()=>{}
    }; // here
    !dev && console = konsole // or no parens here
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that would iterate the `console` properties and overwrite the methods:

```
const noop = (...args: any[]): any => {};

const disable = (con: Console) => {
  (Object.keys(con) as (keyof Console)[])
    .forEach((key) => {
      if(typeof con[key] === "function" ) {
        con[key] = noop;
      }
    });
};
```

[working example](https://replit.com/@StefanTeneff/consolenoop)