# how can I enable/ disable console.log from the browser console

Tags: javascript, console, console.log

I have a load of console.logs in my code, but I only need to see them/ turn them on if I need to see them on a site,  so I want a way to be able to enable/ disbale them from in browser console by setting up a couple of snippets, such as: adysis.debug('enable') , adysis.debug('disable') but how can i get these to them trigger the console.logs in the code,  I got no clue at all at the moment on how to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to quickly and conveniently disable all console.log statements in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215392/how-to-quickly-and-conveniently-disable-all-console-log-statements-in-my-code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable ALL the console's methods use `Proxy`.

Use `console.enabled = true/false` in the browser console to disable/enable console.
The disabled state is persisted in the local storage. So it's the same after a page reload.

(Remove `try/catch` since it's not allowed here).

```js
{
  const key = 'console-enabled';
  
  let enabled;
  try{
  enabled = localStorage.getItem(key);
  }catch(_){}
  
  window.console = new Proxy(window.console, {
    get(console, prop){
      if(prop === 'enabled'){
        return disabled;
      }
      if(!enabled && typeof console[prop] === 'function' && console.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
        return function(){}
      }
      return Reflect.get(...arguments);
    },
    set(console, prop, val){
      if(prop === 'enabled'){
        enabled = val;
        try{
          enabled ? localStorage.setItem(key, val) : localStorage.removeItem(key);
        }catch(_){}
        return true;
      }
      return Reflect.set(...arguments);
    }
  });
}


console.log('disabled');
console.dir(document.body);

$pre.textContent = 'console.log is enumerable: ' + console.propertyIsEnumerable('log');

console.enabled = true;

console.log('enabled');
console.dir(document.body);
```

```html
<pre id="$pre"></pre>
```

Comment: how do i turn it on/ off in browser console?  i need a "dummy" method/ drop in, i aint a good coder lol

Comment: @DavidStanton fixed, you can use `console.disabled = true/false`

Comment: this leaves logs on to start, i want off to start, so can turn on?

Comment: @DavidStanton fixed, put `console.disabled = true` right in the beginning or use the second option where the console is disabled at the start

Comment: ok, i see now logs OFF to start, but if I have a "snippet" that has: console.enabled = true; and "run" it, the logs dont appear, not evn on refresh?

Comment: @DavidStanton in the second snippet `console.enabled = true` works fine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255098/discussion-between-david-stanton-and-alexander-nenashev).

Comment: it only works "in code" not from in browser console, which deafeat the object of what i'm trying to do, which is be able to turn it on/ of from in browser console?

Comment: ah hang on, it does "sort of" work, but it only shows the logs that take place after turned on, not "all" the logs on turn on and doesnt work on "refresh" so as to try and get "all" logs

Comment: @DavidStanton i see, you want to disable/enable permanently

Comment: ye, especially on "page refresh" so as it shows "all" the logs

Comment: @DavidStanton, done, you can disable/enable in the browser console

Comment: thnaks for the help here, much appreciated but this seems to have chnaged to the oposite again now, its "logs on" first page load, but should be "logs off".  I'm trying to use this accross multiple websites, where my "code lives", so i want a "normal user" to not see the logs, but i have the abilty to go to the site turn on/ off, default/ start point is off

Comment: @DavidStanton done, disabled by default you should enable it in the console by typing `console.enabled = true`

Comment: I've forund a problem with this, it errors out in Safari and blocks the page from loading, throwing "TypeError: Object.hasOwn is not a function,  this seems to be beacuse there is nothing in localstorage on this forst page view, if i fire the "console.enabled = true" and refresh, its works but this is going to break the page for pretty much 100% of people , as they wont know to use this, as its for me, for debugging.  Any ideas on a fix for Safari?

Comment: It actually stops Safari working if you then turn off the logs with: console.enabled = false, throws "TypeError: Object.hasOwn is not a function. (In 'Object.hasOwn(console, prop)', 'Object.hasOwn' is undefined)"

Comment: @DavidStanton hasOwn supported from safari 15.4. just change it to console.hasOwnProperty(prop)

Comment: @DavidStanton updated the answer's code