# Print value of JavaScript variable in console

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript variable that is storing some values.

Can I echo it in Firebug or somewhere to see what values are being stored?

```
var p = user.permissions;
```

Comment: in chrome, you can use console.log(value);

Comment: I think console.log works in every js debugger that has a console.

Comment: i get this error: console.log(p);
ReferenceError: p is not defined

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript: How do I print a message to the error console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164397/javascript-how-do-i-print-a-message-to-the-error-console)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Never mind. I had to add this line

```
var p = user.permissions;
```

Before:

```
console.log(p);
```

I was just typing console.log(p);

Comment: is there a way to display the runtime value of a variable by printing the value of the variable using some console commands?