# What do you call it when

Tags: javascript

This is more that i don't know the terminology to Google to get the answer i need

example console.log()

where log is a sub function of console, what is the name/syntax of this sort of function?

Comment: See this-: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164397/javascript-how-do-i-print-a-message-to-the-error-console

Comment: @suspectus — The question is about the terminology given to functions that are values of properties, not about how to use `console.log`.

Comment: got it thanks for all the help guys

<script>
    function testsole() {
        this.info = info;
        function info(string) {
            console.info(string);
        }
        this.log = log;
        function log(string) {
            console.log(string);
        }
        this.warn = warn;
        function warn(string) {
            console.warn(string);
        }
        this.error = error;
        function error(string) {
            console.error(string);
        }        
    }
    
    console = new testsole()
    console.error("hello world");
</script>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions that are properties of an object, and called in the context of that object are usually known as *methods*.

The [EMCAScript (being "standard" JavaScript) specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.27) has the following definition:

> **method**
>
> function that is the value of a property

Comment: or alternativly *Member functions*, but it depends on community/language