# How to resolve "Uncaught TypeError: console is not a function script.js:1:1 " error

Tags: javascript, console, typeerror

I simply create a **script.js** and connect it with **index.html**
In script.js i write ***console("Hello World from js");***

I want to see the console statement *Hello World from js* in the browser console. So I go to Console,  RC>Inspect>Console,
[Browser Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWOvw.png)
There i get an error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wlrcc.png)

Could anybody help me with this issue?

I want to see a clear output ***Hello World from js*** in Browser Console

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I print to the console using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733505/how-can-i-print-to-the-console-using-javascript)

Comment: `console` is not a function - also, for future reference, post CODE in a question, not pictures of code

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use just `console`, you need to specify  a function like log, warn, error, etc.

```
console.log("The Program works");
//Logs to console

console.info("The user is running Firefox")
//A message to inform

console.debug("Some debugging message")
//Used to debug a program

console.warn("Some warning message");
//Warns of something not right

console.error("Error: Something has gone wrong");
//Something has failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to write `console.log('hello world')`.